# Fix (freeze) y axis for Android GraphView package

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I need a way to fix the y axis for the graph view package. I am showing real time frequency spectra but it is not possible to visualise the data properly as the y axis adjusts to the current largest value. Please advise. I will offer a bounty to any answer that easily solves my problem.

Package: http://android-graphview.org/#documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you know the range if Y axis, the method   setManualYAxisBounds(max,min) can be used. For example, if you are using a sin function,

```
graphView.setManualYAxisBounds(1,-1);
```

Or if yours is a percentage graph,

```
graphView.setManualYAxisBounds(100,0);
```

If you have the values to be plotted in an array, again the method can be used with the max and min values of the array (with formatting looks neater).